# Non-Angular alternative to "Mobile Angular UI"

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, mobile-website

I want to build a mobile web app, and I like a few of the features of [Mobile Angular UI](http://mobileangularui.com/demo). My favorite features are:

- The way momentum scrolling is set up
- Allowing toolbar items at the bottom to be clicked without interfering/activating iOS Safari's navigation toolbar
- Overall how well catered it is to making a mobile web app *feel* like a native mobile app

The problem is, it looks as if Angular knowledge is required for usage.

I know *nothing* about Angular, and I don't want to spend a lot of time learning Angular if there is an alternative. Especially since I already know native HTML/CSS/JS quite well.

Is there an **alternative to Mobile Angular UI**, that includes those **3 features I listed** that *doesn't* require knowledge of Angular JS?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap(Responsive Design) or Material Design Lite

Comment: JESUS Material Design Lite is beautiful, thank you for the answer!